# EaselJs performance issue for many sprite classes

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I would like to ask whether does easeljs has performance issue for many sprite class objects? It seems that from my [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/derr/pen/jqNBpj), its terribly lagging...below's code as follows:

```
              var $window = $(window),
          wh = $window.innerHeight(),
          ww = $window.innerWidth();

          var stage = new createjs.Stage("sceneStage");
          var w, h, drone;
          var runnerSprite2, runnerContainer, drone2, droneContainer, robot;
          var robot__movement_speed = 1;
          var building_right, building_left;


          var queue        = new createjs.LoadQueue(),
          $state       = $('#state'),
          $progress    = $('#progress'),
          $progressbar = $('#progressbar .bar');



          queue.on('complete',     onComplete);
          queue.on('error',        onError);
          queue.on('fileload',     onFileLoad);
          queue.on('fileprogress', onFileProgress);
          queue.on('progress',     onProgress);


            queue.loadManifest([
              {
                id: '2',
                src: 'images/sprite_robot_test_plus_toss.png'
              },
              {
                id: '3',
                src: 'images/Drones-Hovering-Loop-12fps.png'
              },
              {
                id: '4',
                src: 'images/sprite_robot_plus_toss.png'
              },
              {
                id: '5',
                src: 'images/sprite_protestor.png'
              }
            ]);



            function onComplete(event) {
              console.log('Complete', event);
              $state.text( $state.text() + '[All loaded]' );
              $progressbar.addClass('complete');
              $('#mainContainer').addClass('hide');
              $('#drone').removeClass('hidden');
              loadScenes();
            }

            function onError(event) {
              console.log('Error', event);
              $state.text( $state.text() + '[' + event + ' errored] ');
            }

            function onFileLoad(event) {
              console.log('File loaded', event);
              $state.text( $state.text() + '[' + event.item.id + ' loaded] ');
            }

            function onFileProgress(event) {
              console.log('File progress', event);
            }

            function onProgress(event) {
              var progress = Math.round(event.loaded * 100);

              console.log('General progress', Math.round(event.loaded) * 100, event);
              $progress.text(progress + '%');
              $progressbar.css({
                'width': progress + '%'
              });
            }


          function loadScenes() {

            // grab canvas width and height for later calculations:
            stage.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            w = stage.canvas.width;
            h = stage.canvas.height;


            //----- Drones --------//
            var data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
              "images": ["images/Drones-Hovering-Loop-12fps.png"],
              "frames": {"regX": 0, "height": 262, "count": 25, "regY": 0, "width": 250},
              "animations": {
                "idle": [0, 24],
                "stun": [0, 0]
              },
              framerate: 24
            });
            drone = new createjs.Sprite(data, "idle");
            drone.setBounds(null, null, 250, 262);
            drone.y = h - drone.getBounds().height;
            drone.x = w - drone.getBounds().width; 
            building_right = drone;

            var drone_left = new createjs.Sprite(data, "stun");
            drone_left.setBounds(null, null, 250, 262);
            drone_left.regX = 250;
            drone_left.y = h - drone_left.getBounds().height;
            drone_left.x = drone_left.regX; 
            building_left = drone_left;


            droneContainer = new createjs.Container();
            droneContainer.addChild(drone, drone_left);
            stage.addChild(droneContainer, runnerContainer);

            var robot_walk_left_arry = [], 
            robot_walk_right_arry = [];

            for(var i = 14; i< 50; i++) {
              robot_walk_left_arry.push(i);
            }
            for(var i = 49; i > 13; i--) {
              robot_walk_right_arry.push(i);
            }
            console.log(robot_walk_right_arry);
            var robot_data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
              "images": ["images/sprite_robot_test_plus_toss.png"],
              "frames": {"regX": 0, "height": 540, "count": 83, "regY": 0, "width": 810},
              "animations": {
                idle: {
                  frames: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
                },
                walk_left: {
                  frames: robot_walk_left_arry,
                  speed: 1 * robot__movement_speed 
                },
                walk_right: {
                  frames: robot_walk_right_arry,
                  speed: 1 * robot__movement_speed
                },
                toss_left: [50, 82, "idle", 0.8 * robot__movement_speed]
              },
              framerate: 24
            });
            robot = new createjs.Sprite(robot_data, "idle");
            robot.setBounds(null, null, 810, 540);
            robot.regX = 405;
            robot.x = (w - robot.getBounds().width);
            robot.y = h - robot.getBounds().height;
            robot._body_dimen = 162;
            stage.addChild(robot);

            var protestor_data = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
              "images": ["images/sprite_protestor.png"],
              "frames": {"regX": 0, "height": 216, "count": 39, "regY": 0, "width": 384},
              "animations": {
                idle: {
                  frames: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
                },
                recovery: [33, 38, "idle", 1],
                nudge: [15,33, "recovery", 1]
              },
              framerate: 24
            });
            var protestor = new createjs.Sprite(protestor_data, "idle");
            protestor.setBounds(null, null, 384, 216);
            protestor.x = 200;
            protestor.y = h - protestor.getBounds().height;

            stage.addChild(protestor);

            drone_left.on("click", function() {
              tweenthis(robot, robot.x, "left");
            });
            drone.on("click", function() {
              tweenthis(robot, robot.x, "right");
            });

            createjs.Ticker.framerate = 30;
            createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
            // createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);

          }

          function handleClick(evt, data) {
              console.log('test');
          }

          function tick(event) {
            stage.update(event);
          }
```

Generally I just create 4 sprite classes with 3 different sprite images. But didn't expect it to be running so lagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protestors image seems to be 8k x 8k pixel in size (with only the top part filled apparently)... That's about 192 MB unpacked... That will bring down any engine... Make sure your animation images are more efficiently packed and of a more reasonable size...

Comment: Thanks Stefan, is there anyway to check how it is unpacked to be about 192MB? And is there any advise for sprite image as the big robot I have, seems to have alot of animation sequence and definitely hit more than 8k x 8k pixels?

Comment: Storing a pixel takes 3 bytes -- one for the red component, one for green and one for blue. If the image contains transparency, there is an additional byte for the alpha channel. To calculated the unpacked memory, just multiply the width by the height by the number of bytes per pixel.

For big animated objects, I'd consider composing them from several smaller ones at runtime, constructing the animation out of the relative movement of the individual parts